Where is the key for Holiday Peak?
Every track in Balloon Slider Mania, a romhack for Super Mario 64, has a hidden key attached to a yellow balloon that unlocks an extra path. I've found the key on every track except for Holiday Peak.
Where is the key to open the hidden path located on Holiday Peak?

Locked door on Holiday Peak

Example of a key in Twilight Canyon

Hug the left wall after the second red balloon but before entering the ice cave. There's a series of small platforms sticking out the side, and the key balloon is on the last one. You may need to slow down to avoid flying over the key.




